# Unable to use OpenCl vector data type

Tags: vector, types, opencl

i am using OpenCL 2.0 C on nvidia graphic card on windows and i want to use the built in vector data types but i can't use them, they are somehow not declared. For example when i try to initialise a float4 vector i get a following error:

```
float4 data_vec = (float4)(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

> error: 'float4' was not declared in this scope

I kept looking in opencl specification but could not find the reason.
though when i try to get the prefered width of any vector type i get 1 as a result for example:

```
cl_uint float_width;
err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[0], 
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT,sizeof(char_width), &char_width, NULL);
printf("%d",float_width);
```

Even if i try `CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT` or `CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_CHAR` I get 1 as a result.

Anyone could tell me the reason?

Thanks

Comment: `float4` is a device type, to be used in kernel code. Where are you using `float4`, on the host or in the device code? On the host you need to use cl_float4. And the accessors are different (more like array notation).

Comment: oh, right that is actually the point, i was using it in host code, i tested it on kernel no error, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll put that as an answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 2):

`float4` is a *device* type, to be used in kernel code. On the host side you need to use `cl_float4`, and the accessors are different (more like array notation).